# Remove Noindex?

Tags: seo, google, noindex

I'm having issues getting Google to index my site, because there is a noindex on the homepage.

`<meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large, noindex, follow' />`

I have removed all SEO plugins, how do I remove this noindex?

The url is `https://hbsleisure.co.uk`

Answer (score 0):

Under wordpress setting -> reading there is a checkbox for preventing indexing of search engines.
`Discourage search engines from indexing this site`.
If its checked, disable it.

[image]